# A search engine which allows users to input 6-digit number and search our database

Tags: php, mysql, database, search-engine

```
<?php
 include "db.php";

 $var = @$_POST['find'];

 //check for empty string and display a message.
 if($var == ""){
echo "<p>Please input a valid 6-digit ID number</p>";
exit;
 } else {

$searchMember = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id='$var'";

$numresults=mysql_query($searchMember);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

if($numrows == 1){
    echo $searchMember['displayname'];
} else if ($numrows == 0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, we couldn't find anything that matches your input. Try again?</p>";
} 
   }

?>
```

I've included information to connect to database in db.php. And here's how the form looks like:

```
<body>
<?php 
include "db.php";
include "searchSystem.php"; 
?>
<form name="search" method="post" action="searchSystem.php">
    Input a 6-digit ID number: <input type="text" name="find" />

    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

So there's a column in my table which has 6digit ID of users. We want to let them search their friends' ID number and look at their profile.

---

So this is what I have just wrote:

```
<?php
include "db.php";

$var = isset($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : '';

//check for empty string and display a message.
if($var == ""){
echo "<p>Please input a valid 6-digit ID number</p>";
exit;

} else {

$searchMember = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id='$var'");
$row_count = $searchMember->row_count();
$result =$searchMember->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row_count == 1){
    echo $result['displayName'].' '.$result['id'];
} else if ($row_count == 0){
    echo "<p>Sorry</p>";
}
}

?>
```

Still doesn't work :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't work'?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: When you run the code, what response do you get?

Comment: @MysticXG It didn't work..because even when I entered a 6-digit number that is already in our database it still responded "Sorry, we couldn't find...."

Comment: @Chibuzo I tried entering a wrong 6digit number...it led me to "Sorry, We couldn't find..." When I tried pressing search button w/o entering anything..it led me to "Please enter a valid 6-digit ID number".. But when I entered a valid 6digit ID that is already in my database, it still led me to "Sorry We couldn't find any..."

Comment: @Quentin Thats the major problem isnt that?

Comment: @VowelChu It looks like your query isn't returning any matches

Answer (score 1):

You have two obvious problems:

- `$tablename` is never defined
- `$searchMember` is a string not an associative array so `$searchMember['displayname']` makes no sense

Comment: $tablename has already been defined in db.php
would that work?

In what way I can have certain column like displayName to be output then?

Comment: Step 1. Throw out the `mysql_*` code. Step 2. Read an introductory PDO tutorial. That will tell you how to use the data returned from a query.

Comment: Thank you! will do it and come back if I've encountered any obstacles

Comment: I've changed something. Would you mind to help take a look of it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong here though if any of them are your actual problem I can't say:

```
$var = @$_POST['find'];
```

Don't suppress errors, instead test for the proper input:

```
$var = isset($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : '';
```

This i highly vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$searchMember = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id='$var'";
```

Instead escape the variable properly:

```
$searchMember = sprinf("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($var));
```

Furthermore `$tablename` is never defined unless its in the file you're including.

`$searchMember` is not an array. I think you mean to reference a result from the query but to do that you need to do:

```
$memberResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($numrows);
echo $memberResult['displayname'];
```

And lastly you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` you should use `PDO` or `Mysqli`.

Comment: I will go ahead and read a PDO tutorial first and let you know after I fix it:) Thank you for the patience thou!

Comment: I've changed something.. Mind to check it for me? I am still stuck here

Comment: `PDOStatement::fetchAll` will give you an array of rows so in order to access a given row you need to do `$result[0]['displayname']` where `0` is the index of the row you want.